# How many ways can 8 persons, including Peter and Paul, sit in a row with Peter and Paul not sitting next to each other?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

The solution I have to this problem is $8!-2\cdot7!$. I don't understand why the $7!$ is multiplied by two.

My solution is that you have a total $8!$ ways to organize 8 people. Subtract all cases where Peter and Paul sit next to each other (6 people, with 7 interstices) so $7C1(6!) = 7!$.

Where do I multiply by two?

Comment: What a perfectly season-appropriate question, given the fact that their [holiday](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feast_of_Saints_Peter_and_Paul) is coming up soon. :-$)$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To count the cases where Peter and Paul sit next to each other, first think of the two as one person (Siamese twins?), so you have $7$ people total, and $7!$ ways to seat them in a row. Then, you need to account for the two ways you can seat Peter and Paul next to each other (Peter on the left, or Paul on the left?).

Comment: simple and clever, nicely done

Comment: Oh, of course. Good stuff, thanks.